# What do I need to add to my javascript to be able use local storage so that when the page is refreshed, the user-selected font-size is still the same?

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage, accessibility, font-size

I'm building a website and just starting to teach myself javascript.  On the website, I've created three buttons that the website user can select to change the font size.  I'm trying to use localStorage so that if the user selects a font size and refreshes the browser, the font size doesn't revert back to the default values written.  This is the code for the buttons and the javascript:

```
<button type="button" id="small_button" role="button" onclick="Small_Font()">A</button>

<script>

function Small_Font() {
    document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize = "16px";
}

</script>


<button type="button" aria-label="medium font" id="medium_button" role="button" onclick="Medium_Font()">A</button>

<script>

function Medium_Font() {
    document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize = "19.2px";
}

</script>


<button type="button" id="big_button" role="button" onclick="Large_Font()">A</button>

<script>

function Large_Font() {
    document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize = "24px";
}

</script>
```

I've looked at this post [How to keep font size always 150% after page refresh or open page again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762884/how-to-keep-font-size-always-150-after-page-refresh-or-open-page-again) , but can't make it work, possibly because I don't have jQuery downloaded.  Any help in how to use local storage in non jQuery javascript for these buttons would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: The answer to the question you linked to shows how to use `localStorage`, and it doesn't require jQuery. You already have code to set the font size, so you can just ignore the jQuery in the answer and use `localStorage` how it is used in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just have one function to do your job just pass the font size from the call and a winodw on load listener which when your page loads will apply the font to the html.

There is a default size '19.2px' say for the first time load or if user never clicked on font-resize function

```
<button type="button" id="small_button" role="button" onclick="font('19.2px')">A</button>
<button type="button" aria-label="medium font" id="medium_button" role="button" onclick="font('16px')">A</button>
<button type="button" id="big_button" role="button" onclick="font('24px')">A</button>

<script>
function font(size) {
    document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize = size;
    localStorage.setItem('fontsize',size);
}

window.onload = function(){
    var g = localStorage.getItem('fontsize') || '19.2px';
    document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize = g;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you need jQuery to save it on localstorage ? its an html5 feature you can simply use JS for it

```
localStorage.setItem('font', JSON.stringify({'font-size':'150px'}));

var retrievedFont = localStorage.getItem('font');

console.log('retrievedFont: ', JSON.parse(retrievedFont));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as a cookie.

```
<script>
function Small_Font() {
    document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize = "16px";
    document.cookie="fontsize=16px";
}
</script>
```

After storing the fontsize as a cookie you need to get the cookies and check them. Below is a function to get cookies with cookie name, which was **fontsize** for you. The reason for that is document.cookie will return all cookies in one string and you need to parse it to get the one you want.

```
<script>
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Now you need to run getCookie function after every page load and update the page style.

```
function myOnLoadFunction
{
    var myfontsize = getCookie("fontsize");
    document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize = myfontsize;
}
```

And to run this onLoad function after every page load you can put it into  tag like this

```
<body onload="myOnLoadFunction();">
```