# localStorage change font color

Tags: javascript

everyone 
I am a begginer at this so please have a patient for me. 
I'got this on my mind, I am traing to change the color of the whole text in p selectors, using LocalStorage, but it dosen't working.

To be clear I have found this code and this is a basic form :
[How to keep font size always 150% after page refresh or open page again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762884/how-to-keep-font-size-always-150-after-page-refresh-or-open-page-again)

And this is mine :

```js
if (localStorage.fontColor)
{
    $('p').css('fontColor', localStorage.fontColor);

}

$("#m").click(function () {
    $("p").css("color", "red");
    localStorage.fontColor = 'red';
});

$("#n").click(function () {
    $("p").css("color", "black");
    localStorage.fontColor = 'black';

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$('p').css('fontColor', localStorage.fontColor);
```

Should be:

```
$('p').css('color', localStorage.fontColor);
```

Comment: Works :D
Thank you, I have another question : haw to add more element to change in this function? You know like font-size ect.