# asp.net mvc5 set font size after page refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

on my webpage, I have two buttons to increase or decrease the font size, after a page refresh the font size goes back to the `<body>` default size despite of using session/local storage, I call this script on my razor html page:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    if (sessionStorage.fontSize) {
        alert(sessionStorage.getItem("FontSize"));
        $('body').css("font-size", sessionStorage.getItem("FontSize"));

    }
        $(".font-button").bind("click", function () {
            var size = parseInt($('body').css("font-size"));
            
            if ($(this).hasClass("plus")) {
                
                size = size + 2;
                if (size >= 27) {
                    size = 27;
                }
            }
            else {
                size = size - 2;
                if (size <= 10) {
                    size = 10;
                }
            }
            $('body').css("font-size", size);
            sessionStorage.setItem("FontSize", size)
        });
    });
```

it is like the line

```js
 $('body').css("font-size", sessionStorage.getItem("FontSize"));
```

would be ignored after refreshing the page...

I hope someone can help me.

ps: this doesn´t work for me:
[How to keep font size always 150% after page refresh or open page again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762884/how-to-keep-font-size-always-150-after-page-refresh-or-open-page-again)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (sessionStorage.getItem("FontSize")) {` instead of `if (sessionStorage.fontSize) {`?

Comment: yes right but the section is entered in both cases, i proofed this by an alert message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unit, i.e. `px`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (sessionStorage.fontSize) {
        alert(sessionStorage.getItem("FontSize"));
        $('body').css("font-size", sessionStorage.getItem("FontSize"));

    }
    $(".font-button").bind("click", function () {
        var size = parseInt($('body').css("font-size"));

        if ($(this).hasClass("plus")) {

            size = size + 2;
            if (size >= 27) {
                size = 27;
            }
        }
        else {
            size = size - 2;
            if (size <= 10) {
                size = 10;
            }
        }
        $('body').css("font-size", size + 'px');           /* added unit */
        sessionStorage.setItem("FontSize", size + 'px')    /* added unit */
    });
});
```